# What's the difference between Anchor Accounts and account attributes?

Tags: anchor, rust, account

When looking at the docs it seems that both `Accounts` and `account` attributes are useful for account serialization, deserialization, and validation. Furthermore, `Accounts` seems to be a derive attribute while `account` is a normal attribute (I'm not too sure what the difference is here either).

While going through a tutorial I see some code like this, and I'm having trouble creating a mental model of what is actually happening:

```
#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct Initialize<'info> {
    #[account(init, payer = user, space = 64 + 64)]
    pub base_account: Account<'info, BaseAccount>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub user: Signer<'info>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}
```

Within the docs it describes `Account` as such:

> ...Implementations of this trait should perform any and all requisite
> constraint checks on accounts to ensure the accounts maintain any invariants required for the program to run securely...

So it makes sense to me that `Accounts` will deserialize and validate the inputs.

But then the `account` attribute is tacked onto multiple other fields too, and this is where I get confused. By the looks of it, `account` seems to handle some sort of verification too, in accordance with the arguments passed in, but what about `account` attributes with no arguments, or fields with no `account` attributes?

It seems redundant to me that `account` is overlapping with `Accounts` and I feel like I'm missing something here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Accounts` is just a trait, while `#[account]` is a macro that generates code.

`Accounts` trait is literally just the below. There is no "functionality".

```
pub trait Accounts<'info>: ToAccountMetas + ToAccountInfos<'info> + Sized {
    fn try_accounts(
        program_id: &Pubkey,
        accounts: &mut &[AccountInfo<'info>],
        ix_data: &[u8],
        bumps: &mut BTreeMap<String, u8>,
        reallocs: &mut BTreeSet<Pubkey>,
    ) -> Result<Self>;
}
```

`#[account]` (and `#[program]`) is doing all the heavy lifting here, including generating an implementation for your `Accounts` struct. If you expand the macros, you will see:

```
#[automatically_derived]
impl<'info> anchor_lang::Accounts<'info> for Initialize<'info>
where
    'info: 'info,
{
    #[inline(never)]
    fn try_accounts(
        program_id: &anchor_lang::solana_program::pubkey::Pubkey,
        accounts: &mut &[anchor_lang::solana_program::account_info::AccountInfo<'info>],
        ix_data: &[u8],
        __bumps: &mut std::collections::BTreeMap<String, u8>,
    ) -> anchor_lang::Result<Self> {
        // ... Generated code handing deserialisation ...
    }
}
```

This would be implementing the deserialisation of the incoming instruction accounts, from a low-level array of `AccountInfo`s to a more ergonomic struct format.

As for a mental model, just imagine that all the `Accounts` struct fields implicitly have `#[account]` on them. We just sometimes need to add more metadata to the account validation, like also check if they are writable so we add an explicit `#[account(mut)]`.

Source code references:

- [Accounts trait](https://github.com/coral-xyz/anchor/blob/205e9d875f9abf1fc379cfc8114c5c53f0207141/lang/src/lib.rs#L62-L87)
- [account macro](https://github.com/coral-xyz/anchor/blob/205e9d875f9abf1fc379cfc8114c5c53f0207141/lang/attribute/account/src/lib.rs)

---

Btw, you may also encounter `#[account]` on structs themselves, like one that would be on `BaseAccount` struct from your tutorial. That has a different purpose. That allows you to define the layout for a "data" account used by the program. In that case, again code is generated to ease serialisation and deserialisation of that account, between low-level byte vectors and a nice struct.